# How to get Visual Studio to use File Scoped namespaces by default

Tags: .net, visual-studio

One of the changes to .Net, which cam in with .Net 6 I think, is the use of file scoped namespaces to reduce nesting.

I have created a solution containing .Net 8 project.

When I create a class using visual studio the default is to still nest the class within the namespace rather than use file scoped namespaces.

I expected it to default to file scoped namespaces as it was a .Net 8 project.

Is there a setting somewhere I need to alter?

Comment: That's [file-scoped namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces), not [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this.

You are right. I now realise I should have asked about "file scoped namespaces".

For clarification I found the full path to the option to be

`Tools > Options> Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Code Block Preferences > Namespace Declarations = 'File scoped'.`

[I also found another solution at www.meziantou.net which was as follows](https://www.meziantou.net/updating-your-project-to-use-file-scoped-namespaces.htm)

- Set preference in the .editorconfig file.
- If you don't have a .editorconfig file, create one at the root of the solution.
- Put the following in the file

```
[*.cs]
csharp_style_namespace_declarations=file_scoped:suggestion
```

**Which option should we go for**

- The former option would presumably need to be altered every time you worked on a solution which contained projects in version which do recognise file scoped namespaces
- I guess the latter is preferable if you are hopping between working on solution of different versions

  - However if the solution contained projects at different versions, perhaps that might be problematic.

Any other considerations?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is [file scoped namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces), not [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements).

To use file scoped namespaces by default, go to Options, Code Style. In the *Code Block Preferences* block change `Block Scoped` to `File Scoped`. [image: Code Block Preferences - Namespace declarations]